# Passing a variable to SSIS at runtime using a script task and vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I have an SSIS package that uses global variables in a WHERE clause of a SQL query to filter on dates inside a Data Flow task. The thing I would like to do is have a Script Task precede the Data Flow task and capture a date from the console. I am trying to program a simple script in VB.net to ask the user for the date and store it in the global variable.

I saw the Script Task has a datepicker control which would be ideal if I could pop it up to capture the date, but barring that, being able to type in the date would be okay.

Several years ago when I was working with SSIS, I remember being able to get the date this way, but I lost my reference to the example code.

Can anyone point me to an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way that an SSIS package can interact with the User in this way.  I'm not sure what you're remembering, but that has never been a possibility.

Here is how I would handle what you want to do:

1. Write a console app (or web app) that takes the user input and stores it in a
   table.
2. Then the console app starts a SQL Agent job that calls the package.
3. In the package, before the dataflow task, add an Execute SQL task
   that queries the table and populates the package variables.